# Grails upgrade from 2.4 to 4.0

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We have a web application running on Grails 2.4 and wish to upgrade to 4.0 so that we will get upgraded to latest spring dependencies . What is the best way to upgrade and below are our questions

1. Upgrade to 3.0 and then upgrade to 4.0
2. Directly upgrade to 4.0.
3. Any step by step document as official documentation is not proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Upgrade to 3.0 and then upgrade to 4.0

For most applications there would not be a good reason to upgrade to 3.0 as an intermediary step.  It will take the same amount of effort to go from 2 to 4 as it would take to go from 2 to 3.

> Directly upgrade to 4.0.

That is what I would do.

> Any step by step document as official documentation is not proper.

The user guide is open source and contributions are welcome.  After you have completed your upgrade if you would like to share it back, please consider submitting pull requests to https://github.com/grails/grails-doc.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. Let me try as its a bigger project upgrade and will document and send pull request if success. This is our opensource effort project from 1.4 version on wards and needs to convince other committers to stick on grails to avoid moving directly to spring boot MVC.